# GCC: how -pie affects address of file scope variable?

Tags: gcc, position-independent-code

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int gprs[32];
int main(void)
{
   printf("%p\n", (void*)&gprs);
}
```

being compiled with `-pie` (seems to be the default) produces:

```
0x55c183951040
```

while being compiled with `-no-pie` produces:

```
0x404060
```

Can someone explain how `-pie` affects address of file scope variable?

Note: Clang seems to have `-no-pie` by default.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone explain how `-pie` affects address of file scope variable?

Using `-pie`, the operating system can load the executable file to any address in memory. Under Windows, this is done using a "base relocation table"; under Linux this is done using "position-independent code".

In this case, many modern OSs load an executable file to any (random) address in memory for security reasons (because it is harder to write a virus accessing the variable `gprs` if its address is not known).

This means that the difference between the addresses of the (`static` or global) variables `a` and `b` in the following example:

```
printf("%p, %p\n", &a, &b);
```

... should be constant but the address of `a` (and `b`) may be different every time you run the program.

Using `-no-pie`, "position-dependent code" is generated under both OSs and no "base relocation table" is generated under Windows.

This means that the executable file can only be loaded into a fixed memory address. And for this reason, the address of a `static` or global variable (but not necessarily of a non-`static` local variable) should not change when you run the program multiple times.